# React JSX does not identify object-fit in style attribute for image

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, jsx, bootstrap-5

I was using bootstrap cards, where I need to set all images in the cards having same size.
Though there are multiple ways of achieving the same but I was using this styling to achieve the same.

Check the image style below

```
<div className="card " style={{width: "18rem"}}>
    <img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top" style={{width: "100%", height: "40vh", object-fit: contain}} alt="..."/>
    <div className="card-body">
        <h5 className="card-title">{title}...</h5>
        <p className="card-text">{description}...</p>
        <a href={newsUrl} target="_blank" className="btn btn-sm rounded-pill btn-primary">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I am getting error

> SyntaxError:
> C:\Users\hpoddar\Desktop\WebDev\ReactComplete\newsapp\src\components\NewsItem.js:
> Unexpected token, expected "," (10:110)

[image]

If I remove the object-fit attribute everything works fine and expected. And the wiggly line goes away.

How can I resolve the same?

```
Bootstrap version : 5.1
react: 17.0.2
react-dom: 17.0.2
react-scripts: 4.0.3
web-vitals: 1.1.2
```

**EDIT :** I had this doubt why object-fit was used as objectFit, which was answered in the comments by Andrew.

> Since the inline CSS is written in a JavaScript object, properties
> with two names, like background-color, must be written with camel case
> syntax:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `object-fit: contain` is not correct for JSX. Try `objectFit: 'contain'`

Comment: But while using vanilla css `object-fit: contain` used to work for me, how come in JSX I need to use it like this `objectFit: 'cover'/contain`. How will I get to know what all things changed, is there any documenation/blog mentioning the same please?

Comment: I official docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html. `Warning:

Since JSX is closer to JavaScript than to HTML, React DOM uses camelCase property naming convention instead of HTML attribute names.

For example, class becomes className in JSX, and tabindex becomes tabIndex.`

Comment: Just by analogy. All kebab-case must transform to camelCase.